# ms-appdata scheme triggers UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified in UWP WebView

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, uwp

I am developing a uwp app with C#.
I have a requirement to download the resources of a website, including images, scripts and html pages so that it can be displayed when offline. I download and save the resources under the local folder. But when I try to access them (from inside a javascript script) the UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified event fires.

Here is a piece of javascript code that uses the resources

```
function startSth(sth,tracking){
    sthAPI.SetSth(sth, tracking);

    var sthUrl = sthBaseUrl + sth.Href;
    if(sth.Parameters !== undefined && sth.Parameters !== null && sth.Parameters !== ""){
        if(sth.Parameters.indexOf('?')===0) sth.Parameters = sth.Parameters.substring(1);
        sthUrl += "?"+sth.Parameters;
    }

    if ( urlParams != "" )
    {
        sthUrl += (sthUrl.indexOf( '?' ) === -1) ? '?' : '&';
        sthUrl += urlParams;
    }
    document.getElementById('mainFrame').src = sthUrl;
}
```

This code tries to access an html page downloaded in local storage and set it as the source of an IFrame. The sthBaseUrl variable is supplied earlier from c# code and is something like `ms-appdata:///local/folder/`

From my understanding the `ms-appdata` scheme is one of the supported schemes of the UWP [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/web-view). I have seen examples where it is used to navigate to content like this `webView1.Navigate("ms-appdata:///local/intro/welcome.html");`

I don't understand why the event fires.

The javascript is not written by me and is a part of a bigger more complex system, so I don't have direct control to have it changed (without a very compelling argument).

Does anybody know of a way to bypass this problem and let the javascript load the page (and other resources) from local storage?

If there is no such way, how can the javascript be modified to achieve this?

This triggers the unsuppoertedUriSchemeIdentified event.

Comment: I don't think you can use the ms-appdata scheme from within a webview. Only when loading via the c# apis of the control. There are some more restrictions, like all files have to be in the same folder in certain cases; and local URLs don't work if you loaded the webview via `NavigateToString`. Lots of odd cases. Sadly, don't remember the exact reasons, because it was over a year ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official documentation:

> WebView supports navigation to URIs using these schemes: `http`, `https`,
>   `ms-appx-web`, and `ms-local-stream`.

1. As far as I see from the code, the problem is that you are navigating to that `sthUrl` in an iframe inside WebView, not the webview it self. That is where this exception is thrown -- and for security reasons you can't navigate to potentially unsecure content.
2. You can't mix in the same (webview) context files from different folders.

   > Each of these first-level subfolders is isolated from the content in other first-level subfolders. For example, you can navigate to ms-appdata:///temp/folder1/file.html, but you can’t have a link in this file to ms-appdata:///temp/folder2/file.html.
3. Finally consider using [`NavigateToLocalStreamUri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetolocalstreamuri.aspx) method. It should allow to wrap locally cached content into a stream that you can reference inside webview via the `ms-local-stream` protocol. Here is a [good description](https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=123) on how it was used in the Web Application Template for exactly offline scenarious.